# How to destroy ImGui::Begin window

Tags: c++, imgui

How I can destroy imgui window by clicking X

```
void test::OnUIRender()
{
    bool state;
    ImGui::Begin("test_test", &state);
    if (ImGui::Button("test")) 
    {
        ImGui::DestroyContext();
    }
    ImGui::End();
}
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37jO6.png)

Comment: Check `state` .

Comment: What function I can use for destroy imgui window without touching main window

Comment: Your `state` variable is:
- Not initialized
- Not preserved across frames, therefore reset every time.
- Not tested by your code e.g. `if (state) { ImGui::Begin(...)` as it should.